# Problem upgrading my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

When I try to upgrade I get this error.

```
wget : Depends: libpsl5 (>= 0.16.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). here
```

The problem is that when I want to search for solution and run them I get this error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1.16.1-1+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.16.1-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.16.1-1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and when I try to solve that error, I get the first one. How do I fix the errors?

Comment: You've tagged 18.04, but I see what looks like eoan (19.10) packages in your second paste.  It looks like you've mixed sources, or other unspecified details are your issue (mixed sources, bad upgrade at fault).  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libgstreamer-plugins&searchon=names